# Jetpack Compose can't import Text or setContent anymore

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I've been messing around with Jetpack Compose recently and I had gone through the basic tutorial [here.](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial) Then I started looking at the Jetnewssample project they have. Now I'm ready to start working on my own project but now  when I create a new project in the same parent directory as the Jetnewssample project, (which is working fine) Android Studio can no longer import androidx.ui.core.Text or androidx.ui.core.setContent. I can import other classes from the same location but now I just get an unresolved reference error. This is a new project set to start with an Empty Compose Activity. Here is the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.compose.Composable
import androidx.ui.core.Text
import androidx.ui.core.setContent
import androidx.ui.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme {
                Greeting("Android")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun Greeting(name: String) {
    Text(text = "Hello $name!")
}

@Preview
@Composable
fun DefaultPreview() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Greeting("Android")
    }
}
```

Here's the module's gradle build file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.franklin.sanctified"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-layout:0.1.0-dev03'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-material:0.1.0-dev03'
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-tooling:0.1.0-dev03'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
}
```

Comment: What does the `build.gradle` file for your module look like?

Comment: Added it to the post

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Those seem to be in `ui-framework` for `dev03`. Try adding that dependency to your lineup:

```
implementation "androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev03"
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! If I may ask, how can you tell where something is located in different versions? I can't seem to figure out how to look at the source code. Is the documentation not up to date?

Comment: @JacobFranklin: "Is the documentation not up to date?" -- Google's documentation tends to lag. "I can't seem to figure out how to look at the source code?" -- for perusing the source code based on artifact version, AFAIK the best resource is my [AndroidX Tech](https://androidx.tech/) site. For example, [this page links to the source files for the `dev03` edition of `ui-framework`](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/ui/ui-framework/0.1.0-dev03). Compose, being function-based, is tedious to analyze. In this case, `Wrapper.kt` has the `setContent()` function, for example.

Comment: @CommonsWare Still getting same Unresolved reference DrawImage() after adding implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-framework:0.1.0-dev03'.

Comment: @Karthikeyan: This question is not about `DrawImage()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178746/unresolved-reference-drawimage for `DrawImage()`. Try the `ui-foundation` artifact.

Answer (score 26):

**Update on :May-2021**

Add below dependencies in app level Gradle or kts file for set content{ .. }

```
implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07")
```

Comment: I still don't understand why the ```setContent``` function is not available in the current (stable 1.4.0) version.

Answer (score 23):

In my case the problem was that I was missing **activities integration** for **compose**. `setContent` is an extension function on `ComponentActivity` class, defined in `package androidx.activity.compose`

Just import:

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.4.0'
```