# Unresolved reference: DrawImage

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, intellij-idea, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying call DrawImage() on my code, I'm following this tutorial
[Jetpack Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial),

But I'm getting this error.:

> Unresolved reference: DrawImage

I tried implement on build.gradle, this lib.:
implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-foundation:0.1.0-dev04'

But I getting this error.:

> Executing tasks: [clean, :app:assembleDebug] in project
>   C:\Users\samue\Desktop\Projetos Kotlin\first-jetpack
>
> Task :clean
>   Task :app:clean
>   Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
>   Task :app:prepareDebugKotlinCompileTask
>   Task :app:generateDebugResValues
>   Task :app:generateDebugResources
>   Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests
>   Task :app:extractDeepLinksDebug
>   Task :app:processDebugManifest
>   Task :app:mergeDebugResources
>   Task :app:processDebugResources
>
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED w: ATTENTION! This build uses unsafe internal compiler arguments:
>
> -XXLanguage:+NonParenthesizedAnnotationsOnFunctionalTypes
>
> This mode is not recommended for production use, as no
>   stability/compatibility guarantees are given on compiler or generated
>   code. Use it at your own risk!
>
> e: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Backend Internal error: Exception
>   during code generation Element is unknownThe root cause
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException was thrown at:
>   androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.irComposableExpr(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:1362)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.CompilationErrorHandler.lambda$static$0(CompilationErrorHandler.java:35)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:93)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm$default(JvmBackendFacade.kt:64)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:52)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmIrCodegenFactory.generateModule(JvmIrCodegenFactory.kt:36)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.doGenerateFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:47)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.codegen.KotlinCodegenFacade.compileCorrectFiles(KotlinCodegenFacade.java:39)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.generate(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:638)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:198)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:172)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:56)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:85)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:43)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:104)     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:349)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:105)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:237)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.access$compileIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:37)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner$compile$2.invoke(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:79)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:91)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:606)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:99)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1645)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
>     at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
>     at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)   at
>   sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   java.util.NoSuchElementException: Collection contains no element
>   matching the predicate.   at
>   androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.irComposableExpr(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:1362)
>     at
>   androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.visitBlock(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:252)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlock(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:128)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlock(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockImpl.accept(IrBlockImpl.kt:52)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrExpression$DefaultImpls.transform(IrExpression.kt:28)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrExpressionBase.transform(IrExpressionBase.kt:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.transformChildren(IrVariableImpl.kt:93)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:283)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildren(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:25)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:46)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:87)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:88)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitVariable(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrVariableImpl.accept(IrVariableImpl.kt:86)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrDeclaration$DefaultImpls.transform(IrDeclaration.kt:42)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrDeclarationBase.transform(IrDeclarationBase.kt:27)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockBodyImpl.transformChildren(IrBlockBodyImpl.kt:49)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:283)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildren(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:25)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:93)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:99)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:100)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitBlockBody(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockBodyImpl.accept(IrBlockBodyImpl.kt:40)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBody$DefaultImpls.transform(IrBody.kt:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.IrBlockBody$DefaultImpls.transform(IrBody.kt)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.expressions.impl.IrBlockBodyImpl.transform(IrBlockBodyImpl.kt:26)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFunctionBase.transformChildren(IrFunctionBase.kt:77)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:283)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.transformChildren(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:25)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitDeclaration(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:46)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:55)
>     at
>   androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.visitFunction(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:205)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:58)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:59)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoid.visitSimpleFunction(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFunctionImpl.accept(IrFunctionImpl.kt:89)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.IrDeclaration$DefaultImpls.transform(IrDeclaration.kt:42)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrDeclarationBase.transform(IrDeclarationBase.kt:27)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.declarations.impl.IrFileImpl.transformChildren(IrFileImpl.kt:71)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.ir.visitors.IrElementTransformerVoidKt.transformChildrenVoid(IrElementTransformerVoid.kt:288)
>     at
>   androidx.compose.plugins.kotlin.compiler.lower.ComposableCallTransformer.lower(ComposableCallTransformer.kt:197)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.LowerKt.lower(Lower.kt:66)   at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$makeIrModulePhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:235)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.PhaseBuildersKt$makeIrModulePhase$1.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:228)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper$runBody$1.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:128)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.downlevel(CompilerPhase.kt:24)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.runBody(CompilerPhase.kt:127)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.AbstractNamedPhaseWrapper.invoke(CompilerPhase.kt:105)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompositePhase.invoke(PhaseBuilders.kt:29)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.common.phaser.CompilerPhaseKt.invokeToplevel(CompilerPhase.kt:42)
>     at org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmLower.lower(JvmLower.kt:288)
>     at
>   org.jetbrains.kotlin.backend.jvm.JvmBackendFacade.doGenerateFilesInternal$backend_jvm(JvmBackendFacade.kt:91)
>     ... 38 more
>
> > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
>
>   > Internal compiler error. See log for more details
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 15s 12 actionable tasks: 12 executed

Can someone help me with this issue?

Answer (score 5):

In your module's `build.gradle` file, make sure that you have this in your `android` closure:

```
  buildFeatures {
    compose true
  }

  composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerVersion "1.3.61-dev-withExperimentalGoogleExtensions-20200129"
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion "0.1.0-dev04"
  }
```

My guess is that you are missing the `composeOptions`.

Answer (score 3):

`DrawImage()` is part of `androidx.ui:ui-foundation`.

Open the `build.gradle (Module: app)` file and add the following line to the list of dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'androidx.ui:ui-foundation:0.1.0-dev03'
}
```

I would recommend following [Jetpack Compose Basics - Codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-basics/#3), a more comprehensive tutorial by Google.

Answer (score 2):

You can see the latest `composeOptions` for the correct build [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose).

But keep in mind that the library API can vary greatly from version to version, and it would be better to take a look at the [official example](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/tree/master/JetNews) to examine the use of the Compose library.

**Don't forget to switch the repository** to the right branch corresponding to the latest version of the library (for example, at the time of the answer it's `dev05` branch).