# Cannot resolve reference to DrawImage() from Jetpack Compose in Kotlin - Android 4.0 Canary Studio

Tags: android, windows, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am following the tutorial on Jetpack Compose - Kotlin for Android [Jetpack Compose Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/tutorial)
Link :

I am unable to resolve reference for `DrawImage()`

I am using Windows 64 bit OS

Comment: I've tried the solution in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60178746/unresolved-reference-drawimage with no luck