# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setContent(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Trying to migrate Android native view to Jetpack compose.

Added dependencies per [Jetpack-compose-migration#3](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-migration#3) in build.gradle

I'm still getting below exception.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setContent(Lkotlin/jvm/functions/Function0;)V in class Landroidx/compose/ui/platform/ComposeView;
```

Any help on this?

Trying to solve this exception.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jetpack Compose can't import Text or setContent anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59340056/jetpack-compose-cant-import-text-or-setcontent-anymore)

Answer (score 1):

Jetpack Compose doesn't use `Activity` class to your activities, it uses `ComponentActivity`.

You can add this implementation to use:

`implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose'`

And in your activity that contains the `setContent` function:

Replace `class MainActivity: Activity()` for `class MainActivity: ComponentActivity()`